# Get the depth of words from a nltk tree

Tags: python, tree, nlp, nltk, spacy

I'm working on a nlp project and I want to filter out words depending on its position in the dependency tree.

To plot the tree I'm using the code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36610179/how-to-get-the-dependency-tree-with-spacy):

```
def to_nltk_tree(node):

    if node.n_lefts + node.n_rights > 0:
        return Tree(node.orth_, [to_nltk_tree(child) for child in node.children])
    else:
        return node.orth_
```

For a sample sentence:

"A group of people around the world are suddenly linked mentally"

I got this tree:

[image]

From this tree what I want to get is a list of tuples with the word and its corresponding depth in the tree:

```
[(linked,1),(are,2),(suddenly,2),(mentally,2),(group,2),(A,3),(of,3),(people,4)....]
```

For this case,  I'm not interested in words which does not have childs: [are,suddenly,mentally,A,the] 
So what I have been able to do so far is to get only the list of words which have children, to do it so I'm using this code:

```
def get_words(root,words):
    children = list(root.children)
    for child in children:
        if list(child.children):
            words.append(child)
            get_words(child,words)
    return list(set(words)

[to_nltk_tree(sent.root).pretty_print() for sent in doc.sents]
s_root = list(doc.sents)[0].root
words = []
words.append(s_root)    
words = get_words(s_root,words)
words

[around, linked, world, of, people, group]
```

From this how can I get the desired tuples with the words and its respective depth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that's an nltk `Tree` in your code? The nltk's `Tree` class does not have a `children` attribute. With an nltk `Tree`, you can do what you want by using "treepositions", which are paths down the tree. Each path is a tuple of branch choices. The treeposition of "people" is `(0, 2, 1, 0)`, and as you can see the depth of a node is just the length of its treeposition.

First I get the paths of the leaves so I can exclude them:

```
t = nltk.Tree.fromstring("""(linked (are suddenly mentally 
                                     (group A (of (people (around (world the)))))))""")
n_leaves = len(t.leaves())
leavepos = set(t.leaf_treeposition(n) for n in range(n_leaves))
```

Now it's easy to list the non-terminal nodes and their depth:

```
>>> for pos in t.treepositions():
        if pos not in leavepos:
            print(t[pos].label(), len(pos))
linked 0
are 1
group 2
of 3
people 4
around 5
world 6
```

Incidentally, nltk trees have their own display methods. Try `print(t)` or `t.draw()`, which draws the tree in a pop-up window.

Comment: I'm using nltk to plot the dependency tree from spaCy that's why it has the "children" method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36610179/how-to-get-the-dependency-tree-with-spacy

Comment: Why this doesn't work for all nodes? `for pos in t.treepositions():
    print(t[pos].label(), len(pos))` Get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'label'`

Comment: Because `nltk.Tree` leaf nodes are strings. Only non-terminals have a label property. Try _my_ code, it works.