# Dependency parsing tree in Spacy

Tags: nlp, spacy, dependency-parsing

I have a sentence **John saw a flashy hat at the store**
How to represent this as a dependency tree as shown below?

```
(S
      (NP (NNP John))
      (VP
        (VBD saw)
        (NP (DT a) (JJ flashy) (NN hat))
        (PP (IN at) (NP (DT the) (NN store)))))
```

I got this script from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36610179/how-to-get-the-dependency-tree-with-spacy)

```
import spacy
from nltk import Tree
en_nlp = spacy.load('en')

doc = en_nlp("John saw a flashy hat at the store")

def to_nltk_tree(node):
    if node.n_lefts + node.n_rights > 0:
        return Tree(node.orth_, [to_nltk_tree(child) for child in node.children])
    else:
        return node.orth_


[to_nltk_tree(sent.root).pretty_print() for sent in doc.sents]
```

I am getting the following but I am looking for a tree(NLTK) format.

```
     saw                 
  ____|_______________    
 |        |           at 
 |        |           |   
 |       hat        store
 |     ___|____       |   
John  a      flashy  the
```

Comment: It looks pretty much like a tree, no? Or I don't understand.

Answer (score 11):

To re-create an NLTK-style tree for SpaCy dependency parses, try using the `draw` method from `nltk.tree` instead of `pretty_print`:

```
import spacy
from nltk.tree import Tree

spacy_nlp = spacy.load("en")

def nltk_spacy_tree(sent):
    """
    Visualize the SpaCy dependency tree with nltk.tree
    """
    doc = spacy_nlp(sent)
    def token_format(token):
        return "_".join([token.orth_, token.tag_, token.dep_])

    def to_nltk_tree(node):
        if node.n_lefts + node.n_rights > 0:
            return Tree(token_format(node),
                       [to_nltk_tree(child) 
                        for child in node.children]
                   )
        else:
            return token_format(node)

    tree = [to_nltk_tree(sent.root) for sent in doc.sents]
    # The first item in the list is the full tree
    tree[0].draw()
```

Note that because SpaCy only currently supports dependency parsing and tagging at the word and noun-phrase level, SpaCy trees won't be as deeply structured as the ones you'd get from, for instance, the Stanford parser, which you can also visualize as a tree:

```
from nltk.tree import Tree
from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordParser

# Note: Download Stanford jar dependencies first
# See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883277/stanford-parser-and-nltk
stanford_parser = StanfordParser(
    model_path="edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz"
)

def nltk_stanford_tree(sent):
    """
    Visualize the Stanford dependency tree with nltk.tree
    """
    parse = stanford_parser.raw_parse(sent)
    tree = list(parse)
    # The first item in the list is the full tree
    tree[0].draw()
```

Now if we run both, `nltk_spacy_tree("John saw a flashy hat at the store.")` will produce [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziAbM.png) and `nltk_stanford_tree("John saw a flashy hat at the store.")` will produce [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZXOv.png).

Answer (score 4):

Text representations aside, what you're trying to achieve is to get a *constituency* tree out of a dependency graph. Your example of desired output is a classic constituency tree (as in phrase structure grammar, as opposed to dependency grammar).

While the conversion from constituency trees into dependency graphs is more-or-less an automated task (for instance, https://www.researchgate.net/publication/324940566_Guidelines_for_the_CLEAR_Style_Constituent_to_Dependency_Conversion), the other direction is not. There have been works on that, check out the PAD project https://github.com/ikekonglp/PAD and the paper describing the underlying algorithm: [http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~nasmith/papers/kong+rush+smith.naacl15.pdf](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/%7Enasmith/papers/kong+rush+smith.naacl15.pdf).

You may also want to reconsider if you really need a constituency parse, here is a good argument: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/7280/why-is-constituency-needed-since-dependency-gets-the-job-done-more-easily-and-e