# how to get height of dependency tree with spacy?

Tags: nlp, spacy

[image]

I have sentence 'today i go to school early'
I want to use spacy and iteration to get the max height (depth) of the dependency tree.

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("today i go to school early")
height = 0
for token in doc:
   root = [token for token in doc if token.head == token][0]
```

I am stuck here and can not navigate further. Could you please help and correct my above code if anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recursive implementation based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36610179/how-to-get-the-dependency-tree-with-spacy)

```
import spacy

en_nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = en_nlp("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.")
depths = {}

def walk_tree(node, depth):
    depths[node.orth_] = depth
    if node.n_lefts + node.n_rights > 0:
        return [walk_tree(child, depth + 1) for child in node.children]


[walk_tree(sent.root, 0) for sent in doc.sents]
print(depths)
print(max(depths.values()))
```

This prints:

```
{'jumps': 0, 'fox': 1, 'The': 2, 'quick': 2, 'brown': 2, 'over': 1, 'dog': 2, 'the': 3, 'lazy': 3, '.': 1}
3
```

---

EDIT:

If you just want the max depth and nothing else, this will do

```
def walk_tree(node, depth):
    if node.n_lefts + node.n_rights > 0:
        return max(walk_tree(child, depth + 1) for child in node.children)
    else:
        return depth


print([walk_tree(sent.root, 0) for sent in doc.sents])
```

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway to return the max value of depth? I tried putting the depths{} inside the function but it does not work well